# Custom linear random number generator

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator, linear-cryptanalysis

I've made an implementation of a linear RNG. It has two constants: `b` and `p`. Every time new value of `a` is generated. Every time a value of `x` is also generated secretly.

The generator computes the number `c` as following:
(a * x + b) mod p == c

All values of `a` `b` `x` `p` are 256-bit numbers and additionaly `p` is prime. I assume the attacker knows the value of `p` and knows a bunch of (eg. 10) values of `a`<sub>i</sub> and `c`<sub>i</sub> computed on the generator as following:

(`a`<sub>1</sub> * `x`<sub>1</sub> + `b`) mod p == `c`<sub>1</sub>

(`a`<sub>2</sub> * `x`<sub>2</sub> + `b`) mod p == `c`<sub>2</sub>

and so on. Values of `x` remain unknown to the attacker and are rather cryptographically random.

My question is: when the attacker has these pairs of known values is it possible for him to calculate the value of `b`? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

What you're essentially computing here is a [universal hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing).
Viewed this way, you have the guarantee that $a_i \cdot x_i \pmod p$ is distributed uniformly over the set $\{0,1,2, ..., p-1\}$ when $a_i \neq 0$. If the $x_i$'s are pseudorandom and independent (not sure if that's what you mean by "rather cryptographically random") then $a_i \cdot x_i$ will be pseudorandom over $\{0,1,2, ..., p-1\}$. You can then view this as a pseudorandom element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ masking $b$. In other words, provided the $x_i$'s remain private, they should all (computationally) hide $b$. Moreover, if the $a_i$'s a public (known by the adversary), they add nothing in terms of security: $x_i + b$ is distributed identically to $a_i \cdot x_i + b$ when $a_i \neq 0$.

However, to formally prove this, you would need to show that if there exists an efficient distinguisher between $a_ix_i + b$ and a random element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then there also exists an efficient distinguisher for your RNG generating the $x_i$'s (a contradiction, assuming the RNG generating $x_i$'s is secure).

Note that calling your construction an "RNG" is a bit of a misnomer, it's really a linear transformation of a (pseudo)random number or alternatively can be viewed as a masking of a secret (see [additive secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing#t_=_n)).